# Detect filled rectangles using OpenCV in java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, tesseract, apache-tika

I am trying to identify the non-text data which is a redaction done by another software(so essentially a black filled rectangle box) in a PDF in which all pages are saved as images. I am able to use Tesseract-ocr with Apache Tika to read the text in the pdf.

In the output, the text is coming as 95% correct but for the black box areas, it prints out characters like -
a OR
iis

I did some research and looks like OpenCV is an option but i am not sure if that will work for my use case. After searching the internet I have found that the best tool for this is OpenCV. I have no experience in OpenCV or image processing itself.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

My code to perform OCR-

````
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        PDFParserConfig pdfConfig = new PDFParserConfig();
        pdfConfig.setExtractInlineImages(true);
        pdfConfig.setExtractUniqueInlineImagesOnly(false); 
        TesseractOCRConfig config = new TesseractOCRConfig();
        ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();
        parseContext.set(TesseractOCRConfig.class, config);
        parseContext.set(PDFParserConfig.class, pdfConfig);
        parseContext.set(Parser.class, parser);

        try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("file.pdf"))) {
            parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, parseContext);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Contents of the PDF:" + handler.toString());```
````

Comment: Are you searching for anything like this https://medium.com/@aashari/simple-rectangle-detection-using-opencv-on-android-48e2a9a0586a ??

Comment: @Arritmic thanks for sharing this but I am looking for something similar to this in plain java. any examples you can share?

Comment: Sorry @devtiwa. But my scope is mainly C, C++ and python. I hope you have luck in your search. Maybe you could start by taking a look to the java examples in OpenCV:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html

Comment: To detect a black box area could be easy if it is different from others - so depending on what "black boxes" you need to detect it could be done - maybe show some images -